# empty schema in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

basically I need to read my Genres and Directors collections in postman but they are just returning empty arrays

this are my schemas:

```js
   // Genre Schema

    let GenresSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    Name: { type: String, required: true },
    Description: { type: String, required: true },
    })

    // Director Schema
    let DirectorsSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    Name: { type: String, required: true },
    Bio: { type: String, required: true },
    Born: Date,
    });


    let Genres = mongoose.model("Genres", GenresSchema);
    let Directors = mongoose.model("Directors", DirectorsSchema);

    module.exports.Genres = Genres;
    module.exports.Directors = Directors;
```

my endpoints:

```js
    // Get all Directors

     app.get("/Directors", (req, res) => {
     Directors.find()
        .then((directors) => {
            res.status(200).json(directors);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.error(err);
            if (queryResult.length == 0) return res.status(404).send("not found");
        });
      });
   

     // Get genres
     app.get("/Genres", (req, res) => {
     Genres.find()
        .then((Genres) => {
            res.status(200).json(Genres);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.error(err);
            res.status(500).sned("Error: " + err);
        });
    });
```

Though I have other movies and users collections I can access through those and perform crud operations but this 2 are only returning empty arrays:C

psdt [this is my repo link](https://github.com/zAndrezz/movie_api.git)

Comment: Do you have any documents in database?

Comment: yea i have a list of 4 directors for the directors collection